# Will different sized bullet crimps fit together?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Will a male crimp bullet fit into a female crimp bullet if the male bullet is 14/16 AWG and the female bullet is 10/12 AWG.  In other words, is the bullet portion of the bullet crimps the same diameter between gauge sizes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec sheets of the [Morris Nylon Insulated Double Crimp Bullet Disconnects](http://www.morrisproducts.com/wire-management/nylon-insulated-double-crimp-bullet-disconnects.asp). There is a blue that will fit the reds, and a blue that will fit the yellows.

[image: Measurements]

[#Red (22-16 AWG)](http://www.morrisproducts.com/images/12052_spec.pdf)
T 0.016
L 0.886
B 0.433
C 0.067
D 0.157
F 0.335
W 0.157

[#Blue 1 (16-14 AWG)](http://www.morrisproducts.com/images/12054_spec.pdf)
T 0.016
L 0.886
B 0.433
C 0.091
D 0.197
F 0.335
W 0.157

[#Blue 2 (16-14 AWG)](http://www.morrisproducts.com/images/12056_spec.pdf)
T 0.016
L 0.886
B 0.433
C 0.091
D 0.197
F 0.335
W 0.197

[#Yellow (12-10 AWG)](http://www.morrisproducts.com/images/12058_spec.pdf)
T 0.016
L 0.925
B 0.512
C 0.134
D 0.256
F 0.335
W 0.197

[image]